# Load css animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a pie chart using css. [This is the link to what I have made](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWvrGE) and now I want to make it animate on scroll, I have used this code

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $('.animation-test').each(function () {
      var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
      var imageHeight = $(this).height();
      var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (imagePos < topOfWindow + imageHeight && imagePos + imageHeight > topOfWindow) {
          $(this).addClass("slice-right");
      } else {
          $(this).removeClass("slice-right");
      }
   });
});
```

But it's not working, why?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your if condition to this

if (imagePos < (topOfWindow + imageHeight )&& (imagePos + imageHeight) > topOfWindow)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this out, change `100` to the number of pixels that have to be scrolled downwards in order to let the animation happen

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height  > 100) {
        $(this).addClass("slice-right");

    }else{
        $(this).addClass("slice-right");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you need. You may have to create some if statements if the height axis point of trigger will be different between mobile and desktop.

[JS Bin Example here](https://jsbin.com/disiqevane/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var height = $(window).scrollTop();
console.log(height);
if(height  > 200) {
    $(".item").addClass("item--newColor");
    $(".item").removeClass("item--color");
}});
```